# Swap rows in the jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on jQuery datatable plugin. When click the down arrow, swap the current row and next row. When click the up arrow, swap the current row and previous row. But I cannot get the index of the particular clicked row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on('click', '.swapDown', function(event){
  var ind = table.row(this.closest("tr")).index();
  var movedData = table.row(this.closest("tr")).data(),
                otherData =table.row(this.closest("tr").prev()).data();
        table.row(this.closest("tr").prev()).data(otherData).draw();
        table.row(this.closest("tr")).data(movedData).draw();
  console.log(ind);
    });

 $('#example tbody').on('click', '.swapUp', function(event){
var ind = table.row(this.closest("tr")).index();
  var movedData = table.row(this.closest("tr")).data(),
                otherData =table.row(this.closest("tr").next()).data();
        table.row(this.closest("tr").next()).data(otherData).draw();
        table.row(this.closest("tr")).data(movedData).draw();
  console.log(ind);
 });
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1289/](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1289/)

Comment: You're using `this` an awful lot and I think you probably want to be using `$(this)` instead. This does your console: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/zqzzyscy/ but I'm not able to move things. I did wonder if it was because you had default ordering on the browser name but I'm not sure as I've removed it and it's still not working as you expected.

Comment: I try to swap the row but i cant `http://jsfiddle.net/zqzzyscy/11/`

Comment: If your table wasn't hard coded and had an arbitrary index you'd be sorted as you could swap the index and the order on the hidden column. But because you've got a hard coded table it's more problematic - bear with and I'll work up a JSFiddle.

Comment: Please check the answer I've posted... It seems to be working but with adapted markup to include an index upon which to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent this morning playing with this and this is what I've got up and running, I'm really not sure it's the best solution but it does work:

```
$(function() {
    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        "order": [
            [0, 'asc']
        ],
        "paging": true,
        "columns": [{
            "visible": false
        }, {
            "orderable": false
        }, {
            "orderable": false
        }, {
            "orderable": false
        }, {
            "render": function(d) {
                return $("<i/>", {
                    "class": "fa fa-caret-down swapable swapDown"
                }).prop("outerHTML");
            },
            "orderable": false
        }, {
            "render": function(d) {
                return $("<i/>", {
                    "class": "fa fa-caret-up swapable swapUp"
                }).prop("outerHTML");
            },
            "orderable": false
        }]
    });
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function(event) {
        // We're only interested in cells with a class of swapable
        if ($(this).find(".swapable")) {
            // Helper variable
            var _this = $(this).find(".swapable");
            // Total number of rows (including hidden rows (zero based index))
            var tableRows = table.data().length - 1;
            // Index of current row
            var rowIndex = table.row(this).index();
            // Data of current row
            var rowData = table.row(this).data();
            // Index value of row (artifical because it's ours) - also tempval
            var artificalIndex = ~~rowData[0];
            /*
             * If we're on the bottom row of the table and the direction of travel is downwards  or if we're
             * on the top row and the direction of travel is upwards then we need to just swap the top and
             * bottom rows
             */
            if(
                    (_this.hasClass("swapDown") && artificalIndex === tableRows)
                    ||
                    (_this.hasClass("swapUp") && artificalIndex === 0)
            ){
                var topIndex, bottomIndex;
                table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                    var data = this.data();
                    if(~~data[0] === 0){
                        topIndex = rowIdx;
                    }
                    if(~~data[0] === tableRows){
                        bottomIndex = rowIdx;
                    }
                });
                table.cell(topIndex, 0).data(tableRows);
                table.cell(bottomIndex, 0).data(0);
            }else{
                var movingIndex, tempData;
                table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                    var data = this.data();
                    // Moving down
                    if (_this.hasClass("swapDown") && ~~data[0] === artificalIndex + 1) {
                        movingIndex = rowIdx;
                        tempData = data[0];
                    }
                    // Moving up
                    if (_this.hasClass("swapUp") && ~~data[0] === artificalIndex - 1) {
                        movingIndex = rowIdx;
                        tempData = data[0];
                    }
                });
                table.cell(rowIndex, 0).data(tempData);
                table.cell(movingIndex, 0).data(artificalIndex);
            }
            table.draw(false);
        }
    });
});
```

[This is a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/o3c6dg14/).

I had some issues with the index as I'm not 100% sure the internal index is refreshed after a `draw()` so I decided to use a hidden index and to order on that. This is the HTML used to create the table:

```
<div class="container">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Swap Down</th>
                <th>Swap Up</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>0</th>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2</th>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3</th>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
                <td>Win 98+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>4</th>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
                <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>5</th>
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
                <td>Win XP</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>6</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>7</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>8</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
                <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>9</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
                <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>10</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Camino 1.0</td>
                <td>OSX.2+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>11</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Camino 1.5</td>
                <td>OSX.3+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>12</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
                <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>13</th>
                <td>Gecko</td>
                <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
                <td>Win 98SE+</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>14</th>
                <td>Misc</td>
                <td>Lynx</td>
                <td>Text only</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hope that helps and I'd appreciate any feedback from the community as to how it might be improved upon as I'm pretty sure I'm missing something...?

Comment: Hey @Learner, sorry about that, try: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/m6q4jc4j/

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with this plugin but @annoyingmouse is right. You probably meant to use `$(this)` instead of `this` as the former creates a jQuery object where you can utilize jQuery methods. Another thing I noticed was that the included DataTables plugin was not the most current version (as per datatables.net). I don't know if this has much effect on your application but the linked fiddle includes the most current version from datatables.net. I also am not sure of the outcome you are expecting from the fiddle, but it does log out an integer in console on 'click'.

Another thing is your table is not necessarily set up correctly. the "Swap Up" th element is inconsistent with the "Swap Up" td element, the same for the "Swap Down"

```
            <th>Swap Up</th>
        <th>Swap Down</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td><i class='fa fa-caret-down swapDown'></i></td>
        <td><i class='fa fa-caret-up swapUp'></i></td>
```

You'll probably want to reverse the td elements. Or the naming convention is just confusing to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1291/